# Why is a list of undef not a read-only or constant value in Perl?

Tags: perl

Consider the following programs in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @foo = qw(a b c);
undef = shift @foo;

print scalar @foo;
```

This will die with an error message:

> Modification of a read-only value attempted at ...

Using a constat will give a different error:

```
1 = shift @foo;
```

> Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at ...
>   Execution of ... aborted due to compilation errors.

The same if we do this:

```
(1) = shift @foo;
```

All of those make sense to me. But putting `undef` in a list will work.

```
(undef) = shift @foo;
```

Now it prints `2`.

Of course this is common practice if you have a bunch of return values and only want specific ones, like here:

```
my (undef, undef ,$mode, undef ,$uid, $gid, undef ,$size) = stat($filename);
```

The 9th line of code example in [perldoc -f undef](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) shows this, butthere is no explaination.

**My question is, how is this handled internally by Perl?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Internally, Perl has different operators for scalar assignment and list assignment, even though both of them are spelled `=` in the source code. And the list assignment operator has the special case for `undef` that you're asking about.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: To what, exactly? Perl's source code is not exactly straightforward. You can look at https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/op.c and search for `op_sassign` and `op_aassign`, if that helps. Or, probably more useful, see the compiled bytecode by doing something like this: `perl -MO=Terse -E '(undef) = 1;'`

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased that differently. What I meant was, can you provide something to back that explanation? Since you did not link to documentation saying that I assumed you had looked for it somewhere else, most likely the source. :)